# Integral of $\int(8-\frac{7}{1+x})^2dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

What is the most **elementary** method for solving $\int(8-\frac{7}{1+x})^2dx$  ?

I am at a loss of how to proceed efficiently and correctly.

This happens to be the little R in a Disk-Method volume problem, with a proposed solution found [here](http://d1e904a9d2f29d135087-eed1f45d229d53e927f9bd3dc4a1fa4e.r14.cf2.rackcdn.com/se07b02019.png). Note: Some values are different in the solution linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int(8-\frac{7}{1+x})^2dx &= \int (64 - \frac{112}{1+x} + \frac{49}{(1+x)^2}) dx \\
&= 64x -112 \ln |1+x| - \frac{49}{1+x} + C
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

Just expand and use the linearity of the integral plus the following
$$
\int\frac{1}{1+x}=\log|1+x|+C
$$
and
$$
\int\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}=-(1+x)^{-1}+C
$$

Answer (score 2):

Put $x+1=u$ hence $dx=du$

Hence integral turns to $$\int (8-\frac 7u)^2 du=\int 64du+\int \frac {49du}{u^2}-\int \frac {112du}{u^2}=64u-\frac {49}{u} -112\ln \vert u\vert+C=64(x+1)-\frac {49}{x+1} -112\ln \vert (x+1)\vert +C$$

Comment: I should I have tried expanding from the start, but it looked scary. I solved it in under 30 seconds once I saw the advice to expand the square. Also, thanks for help with the tags.